# Java 8 stream.collect(Collectors.toMap()) analog in kotlin

Tags: java, sequence, java-stream, kotlin, collect

Suppose I have a list of persons and would like to have `Map<String, Person>`, where String is person name. How should I do that in kotlin?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/q/34639208/97777

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34642254

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Assuming that you have

```
val list: List<Person> = listOf(Person("Ann", 19), Person("John", 23))
```

the [`associateBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate-by.html) function would probably satisfy you:

```
val map = list.associateBy({ it.name }, { it.age })
/* Contains:
 * "Ann" -> 19
 * "John" -> 23
*/
```

As said in KDoc, `associateBy`:

> Returns a `Map` containing the values provided by `valueTransform` and indexed by `keySelector` functions applied to elements of the given array.
>
> If any two elements would have the same key returned by `keySelector` the last one gets added to the map.
>
> The returned map preserves the entry iteration order of the original array.

It's applicable to any `Iterable`.

Comment: `toMap()` has changed to `toMapBy()` in current Kotlin, can you please update the answer.

Comment: For other equivalents between `Stream.collect` and Kotlin, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34642254/what-is-the-java-8-stream-collect-equivalent-in-kotlin

Comment: @JaysonMinard, thanks, updated the answer, also used another `toMapBy` overload which is closer to `Collectors.toMap`.

Comment: Coudn't find `List.toMapBy`... maybe missing an import. However `.keysToMap {transform(it)}` was exactly what I was looking for to replace `.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), {transform(it)}))`.

Comment: @TWiStErRob, the `toMapBy` function seems to have been renamed to [`associateBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/associate-by.html). Thanks for noticing that, I'll update the answer.

Comment: Actually, don't use `keysToMap` or `associateBy(identity(), {...})` (`associateBy` is OK, `identity()` is not!), both of these are internal to Jetbrains (`org.jetbrains.kotlin.utils`), not public Kotlin API (`kotlin.*`). They lurked in via `gradle-kotlin-dsl` and `kotlin-compiler-embeddable`. Depending on these may cause ClassNotFoundExceptions.

Answer (score 4):

Many alternatives in Kotlin :)

```
val x: Map<String, Int> = list.associate { it.name to it.age }
val y: Map<String, Int> = list.map { it.name to it.age }.toMap()
var z: Map<String, Int> = list.associateBy({ it.name }, { it.age })
```

The best option for this particular case IMO is the first as Lambdas are not needed but simple transformation.